# JAVA: Unformed Sprite When trying to Read SpriteSheet

Tags: java, sprites, image

So Im a beginner experimenting with ImageIO. Can someone tell me why im getting this pixelated-incomplete sprite?

[image]

Here's the code

```
public BufferedImage getImage(String location)
{
    try 
    {
        File file = new File(location);

        image = ImageIO.read(file);
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        System.err.println("It don't work!!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return image;
}
```

And Im using this method to display it

```
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    g.drawImage(getImage("Numbers/icon0.png"), 0, 0, 32, 32, null);
    repaint();
}
```

THANK YOU IN ADVANCE

Answer (score 1):

your code actually draws a scaled image, have a look at [Chris Campells article](https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/04/03/perils-of-image-getscaledinstance.html), it's really useful...

what you have to do to simply draw the whole image without scaling...

```
g.drawImage(getImage("Numbers/icon0.png"), 0, 0, null);
```